# Is there any difference using UTF-8 double and single quote

Tags: xml

Is there any difference when I'm using double and single quote for UTF-8?

- `encoding="utf-8"`
- `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: For `declare()` or the `<?xml` PI? And, what made you assume there's a difference? In what context?

Comment: depends on context, but usualy its just to ease of use of quotes inside quotes. You have to quote double quotes inside double quotes (`"\""`), and you have quote single quote inside single quotes (`'\''`). Where single quote inside double quotes is fine (`"'"`) same as double quote insode single quotes (`'"'`).

Comment: for <?xml . I'm not assume, I just look at some codes. Some people write it in single quote, some write it in double quote. From my knowledge, I think it is no different. I'm not sure, then I ask this question

Comment: In the *specific* case in the question there might be no difference, however, there *is* an important difference in PHP (since you flagged the question) - double-quotes will expand interpolated variables and backslashed characters, single-quotes won't, they'll treat them literally. Try `$colour = "pink"; echo "$colour elephants\n"; echo '$colour elephants\n';`

Comment: woahh.. Okay then, you just made me better understanding. Thank you @CD001